# Best approach for end to end testing for integration of web, hardware and desktop in Ci/CD?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, integration-testing, end-to-end

I have a very unique application that involves a web portal, USB hardware dongle license and windows executable utility that configures the hardware

1. As a customer buy a USB dongle hardware in a web online store for a CAD
   desktop app
2. As a sales fulfillment person check the order and,
   insert a brand new USB dongle into a computer
3. Configure the dongle with an executable that burns product information on it. The information is posted to the database
4. Insert the product inside the customer's account using the web portal
5. Simulate a customer receiving the dongle and generating keys for security, to run the software or for upgrades

Problem: how to effectively run stable tests that will prove the real data works?

Approaches:
1-Cypress on steps 1,2, then UIpath on step 4, then cypress again on step 5
Note: both communicating via API. UIpath will have a dedicated computer to run that. It could be very unstable but the good thing is that Cypress is fast, easier to maintain (development team can do) and can cover a lot of cases not related to the dongle

2-Selenium on all these steps
Challenge: slow and very high maintenance, I don't have a dedicated QA team

3-A mixed approach, so cypress is used with mockup data completely separate from and selenium repeats some of that. There are other functions on the platform such as customer information, invoices that are not related to dongles which could be tested with cypress. Note: The cost of simulating the dongle is very high and it was proven that the real data works very differently. Maintenance will also be expensive

Comment: Why do you think Selenium is slower and requires more maintenance significantly more then Cypress ?

Comment: My team does not know selenium. We know Javascript. My backend dev is php, I'm a UX designer with some JS and we don't have QA

Comment: Why can't you use protractor, currently Cypress supports only chrome I guess

Comment: I could use Protactor, but isn't it for Angular? what about the Desktop part?